# Display custom fields for custom type into fixed textbox to be edited?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type `medicine`, and added custom fields with values.
How to show those custom fields in admin editor so that the user can add value for `new 'medicine'`?

**Current situation**:
[image: Current screen]

**Desired Situation**:
[image: Desired screen]

Is there any custom code or plugin that I missed while searching?

Note: Uploading images directly to this post always gives error...so I have to put the direct link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:

Using [NaviCat for MySQL](https://www.navicat.com/download/navicat-for-mysql)

I import custom post type into `wp_posts` manually

Then I imported the custom fields manually into enter code here `wp_postmeta`

- Keep in mind you need to fix `post_id` for both import.

Then exported the custom post type and then re-imported it to fix the permalink

and it work like charm!